# How to build two Android apps in one Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I have a project in Android Studio. I would like to be able to build two Android apps from the same project. For example, the project contains two files: **ActivityA.java** and **ActivityB.java**.

I would like to be able to build one Android app where **ActivityA** is the main launcher and another Android app where **ActivityB** is the main launcher. When building the project, I'd like it to generate two .apk files. Is this possible? What would I need to configure to make ActivityA the main launcher for app #1 and ActivityB the main launcher for app #2?

Comment: All possible. You should start here: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html. Read about flavors. Also read this: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html for the ActivityA/ActivityB question.

Answer (score 3):

Create two folders/flavors AppA and App2 similar to the picture below:

[image]

They both have a manifest like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.onegravity.testapplication.ActivityA">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Make sure that the manifest in the main project folder doesn't define a launcher Activity.

If you use the same package name for the two apps then defining those two flavors in the Gradle script becomes simply:

```
productFlavors {
    AppA {}
    AppB {}
}
```

(put that below the buildTypes block).

Please read this to get a good understanding of flavors and what you can do with them:
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants
http://developer.android.com/tools/building/manifest-merge.html

Comment: Thanks @Emanuel ! This is a really helpful answer.  Let me try it out and let you know how it goes.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't hesitate to mark it as correct ;-)

Answer (score -3):

Sounds really messy.

I can see building two applications from a common code base but since the 
manifest only accepts one application element you would have to change the manifest when you build.

If the problem is a common code base why not create a library with the common code and then import the library as a module in two separate projects.

Comment: That's what you did back in the Eclipse days. With Gradle building two apks with different build config including different main Activities is a piece of cake.

Comment: Fair enough, I was reading this as " Can I do this from my UI without using a build script".

Comment: "What would I need to configure to make [...]". Configuration imo includes build scripts but then only the OP knows...

Comment: @mjstam This functionality is very needed and important for some types of software projects. Your idea with library really slows down development process. Normally you don't do library during active development. You do library when development is done and you think that the part of your code could be useful in other projects - then you do a library.